# How to know if I've reached the last 'li' item

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

I've made a slide-show with 'li' tags and jquery.

The whole 'ul' moves to the left or right respective to the Next/Prev buttons and has a width equal to the total width of all the slides put together, i.e. 700px each. And only 1 slide is allowed to show in the viewport of width equal to 700px. But when I click next the show goes on even though there's no more slides.

The solution is to hide the Next button when the last slide shows up in the viewport. How do I do that?

Or maybe another solution is welcome...

This is my simplified code:

```
var slideList = $('#slideWindow ul')

$('#next').click(function(e){

    slideList.animate({ 'left': '-=700px' });

    if( $('li:last').next() === 0 ){

        $(this).hide();

    } else {

        $(this).show();

    }

    return false;

});
```

Comment: Could you provide a link or a jsfiddle of your slider to see where the button is exactly placed ?

Comment: @CronosS: Thanks for your response, but it's not about where the buttons are placed, it's about how they work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If there is a particular class `classBeingViewed` applied to `li` that is being viewed at the moment, you can just do:

```
if($('li').last() == $('li.classBeingViewed')){
    $(this).hide();
else {
    $(this).show();
}
```

Or you can keep track of the index. This is preferable since it allows animations in both directions.

```
var slideList = $('#slideWindow ul');
var listIndex = 0;
var numLiElements = $('li').length;

$('#next').click(function(e){
    slideList.animate({ 'left': '-=700px' });
    if( listIndex == numLiElements ){
        $(this).hide();
    } else {
        listIndex += 1;
        $(this).show();
    }
    return false;
});
```

Then, you can decrement `listIndex` in a click handler to `$('#previous')` when you want to reverse the animation.